# - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations is not getting called through a custom framework in project

Tags: objective-c, ios9, shouldautorotate

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations is not getting called in a custom framework which I have used in my project's UIViewController, while in separate project it is working fine and getting called properly

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
    return YES;
    }
  - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
  - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }

Is there any way to get it called through a custom framework in a project?

Comment: having the same issue. Need help too...

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons to happen this. Once check this.[image]

In Devices check iPad and iPhone orientations and select only Portrait. Then delegate methods will call.